# task-scheduler: How can all users view/edit/run the same tasks?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I want all (or selected) users/admins to view/edit/run the same task. It seems that each user/admin only sees his own tasks and not the others users'.

This is quite confusing for me since on Linux a user with the right permissions can view/change all cron jobs. So the jobs are tied to the machine and not to the user on the machine.

Comment: Do you apply any special GPOs? From my experience you are able to see all tasks in the task scheduler (`taskschd.msc`). Changing them might require different privileges.

Comment: I have no access to GPO.

Answer (score 3):

By default scheduled tasks are user specific, that's why you can only see "your own" tasks. If you choose to create a "normal" task (not the simple task), you will get the option to choose a specific user or a user group.

Choosing - for example - a system account or a user group should make it visible to other users as well (assuming they have sufficient rights to view it). I haven't tried this on a recent version of Win10 but as far as I remember it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to task export / import:

```
Get-ScheduledTask
$xml = Export-ScheduledTask -TaskName Abc -TaskPath \Xyz\
Register-ScheduledTask -Xml $xml -TaskName Abc -TaskPath \Xyz\ -User Xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 10 permissions are stored in registry. You can edit those settings with a script. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1046122/471857).